# Kotlin-android: Unresolved reference

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have received this project from the previous developer, and he said everything is working fine on his end. But on my end, when I try to sync the project I get a lot of errors, and I don't know where to even start. One of them is this:

[image]

Here's that code:

```
private fun setupScrollDirection() {
        val allowHorizontalScroll = config.scrollHorizontally && config.viewTypeFolders == VIEW_TYPE_GRID
        excluded_vertical_fastscroller.isHorizontal = false
        excluded_vertical_fastscroller.beGoneIf(allowHorizontalScroll)

        excluded_vertical_fastscroller.allowBubbleDisplay = config.showInfoBubble
        excluded_vertical_fastscroller.setViews(manage_folders_list) {
            excluded_vertical_fastscroller.updateBubbleText(getBubbleTextItem(it))
        }
    }
```

I have a lot more errors of the same type, like this one for example:

[image]

Comment: if any dependencies have been used and you have updated them after you received the project. some method might have been deprecated and removed from the library so how about you start from checking for that.

Comment: Yes, I have updated many dependencies. I've tried Google-ing those methods, but it's like they don't exist.

Comment: It doesn't look like they exist

Comment: That's weird...

Answer (score 1):

Please have a call with the other developer and ask him/her to share his screen on call.

When the screen is being shared, ask the developer to `Ctrl+ Click` on `beGoneIf` variable/function and then check where the `beGoneIf` is defined in the project. This way you can check whether the required library/dependencies used by other developer is present in your local project or not.